# Haskell creating a greedy zip function

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a greedy zip method in Haskell where it does not drop the elements, instead, it will use some default value. I appreciate any feedback to make it more compact.

```
zip' [-1] [] r = r
zip' [] [-1] r = r

zip' [] b r  = zip' [-1] b r
zip' a [] r  = zip' a [-1] r

zip' a b r  = (xa, xb) : (zip' xsa xsb r)
  where
    (xa: xsa) = a
    (xb: xsb) = b

main = do
  let l1 = [1, 2, 3]
  let l2 = [3, 4]
  print (zip' l1 l2 [])
  --  expected: [(1,3),(2,4),(3,-1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` is always `[]`. Simpler library functions can do some of the work.

```
zip' [] b = map (-1,) b
zip' a [] = map (,-1) a
zip' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, y) : zip' xs ys
```